# Rotate an object relative to self cordinates (not global cordinates)

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, rotation, trigonometry

first of all sorry but i don't talk english very well. So i hope i will be able to explain myself the best i can. As the title say i'm trying to rotate an object so that the object rotates according to how it's axis are rotated. I know my purpose is weird but the truth is that i'm just trying to playing with rotations in order to understand them. Actually searching on the internet i found how to do that but the problem is that i need to use clamped values and so i need to find another method of doing that. I will paste the code so that you can understand better. Please feel free to suggest me another way to solve my problem.

```
 [Header("Camera")]
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _xMinMaxRotation = new Vector2(-90, 90);
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _yMinMaxRotation = new Vector2(-90, 90);
    [SerializeField] private float _mouseXSensistivity = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float _mouseYSensistivity = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float _mouseZSensistivity = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float _xStartRotation = 0;
    [SerializeField] private float _yStartRotation = 0;
    private Vector2 _mouseDelta;
    private float _rotY, _rotX, _rotZ;

    public GameObject head;

    void Start() {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update() {
        _mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        MoveCamera();
    }


    private void MoveCamera() {
        if (_mouseDelta.x != 0) {

            _rotX = _mouseDelta.x * _mouseXSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
            _rotX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotX, _xMinMaxRotation.x, _xMinMaxRotation.y);
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, _rotX, 0);
        }
        if (_mouseDelta.y != 0) {
            _rotY = _mouseDelta.y * _mouseYSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
            _rotY = Mathf.Clamp(_rotY, _yMinMaxRotation.x, _yMinMaxRotation.y);
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(-_rotY, 0, 0);
        }

        //Calculation for RotZ
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) {
            _rotZ = _mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);

            if (_rotZ > 25) _rotZ = 25;
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);

        }
        else {
            if (_rotZ > 0) {
                _rotZ = 2 * _mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
                transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);

                if (_rotZ < 0) _rotZ = 0;
                transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);

            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
            _rotZ = -_mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);


            if (_rotZ < -25) _rotZ = -25;
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);


        }
        else {
            if (_rotZ < 0) {
                _rotZ = 2 * -_mouseZSensistivity * Time.deltaTime * 50;
                transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);


                if (_rotZ > 0) _rotZ = 0;
                transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, _rotZ);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't have any parent in my gameObject so i cannot use stuff like transform.localRotation or localEulerAngles. Imagine like if i have a character and instead using the world coordinates to rotate his POV i want to do that using its own axis orientation. I could use the method tranform.Rotate and pass as second parameter the self orientation, it would work. But i want to find a way to rotate my gameObject on the y axis until certain limits. FOr example clamping the values to a minimum of -90 and maximum of 90. As i said fell free to change my code and suggest me the best option you think. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know enough about unity to tell whether this is the answer you need, but typically the difference between local and global transformation corresponds to the order in which you combine them. So where you currently write `transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(…)` try swapping the order for that multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes is what i learned as well but as i said my goal is to find a way to clamp the axes rotations on a min and max values and then i need a method to rotate object on its relative coordinates system with clamped values!